# How to get files name within subfolders without the route in GCS using Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket with lots of subfolders, I use this function to get blobs but I need to get the filenames how can this be done?

```
def list_blobs_with_prefix(bucket_name, prefix,delimiter=None):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=prefix,delimiter=delimiter)
    return blobs
```

I need to get filenames without the folders route, to use it in another function, that function tries to download the file and put it in a temp folder.

Comment: What is your problem? Pain point?

Comment: The problem is by blob.name I can get the folder name along with the file name. I need to get just the file name.

Answer (score 3):

This script will provide you with a list including only the filenames inside of your bucket without the folder/subfolder/ route

```
from google.cloud import storage


client = storage.Client()
BUCKET_NAME = 'thehotbucket'
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

blobs = bucket.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:
    try:
        num = blob.name.count('/')
        string = blob.name.split('/')[num]
        if string != "":
            print(string)
    except:
        print("An exception occurred")
```

Comment: @Kolban - I am guessing because this code prints all objects and not objects from a  specified folder. The feature of `prefixes` is not obvious when first writing code.

Comment: blob.name will return subfolder/filename.I need to return the file name which the path is like bucket/folder/file.

Comment: OK now I think I understand your question. Instead of the proposed Print try the following: `print(blob.name.rindex('/')+1:)` this should work but I'm out of the city and don't have a pc to try this now but please let me know if this works for you

Comment: This will return one character of the path. :)

Comment: By using blob.name.split('/') can seperat the folder and file name.

Answer (score 1):

Given any list of *string* paths (this doesn't apply only in your application), the file can be taken as follows:

```py
from pathlib import Path


def get_files(*paths: str, *, sep='/') -> list[str]:
    return [path.rpartition(sep)[-1] for path in paths]


def get_files(*paths: str) -> list[str]:
    return [Path(path).name for path in paths]
```

For your specific case this changes to:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable


def get_files(blobs: Iterable) -> list[str]:
    return [blob.name.rpartition('/')[-1] for blob in blobs]


def get_files(blobs: Iterable) -> list[str]:
    return [Path(blob.name).name for blob in blobs]
```

Also, you can easily strip the file suffix out from the names:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable


def get_files(blobs: Iterable) -> list[str]:
    paths = [Path(blob.name) for blob in blobs]
    return [path.name.rpartition(path.suffix)[0] for path in paths]
```